# How call Rest API in Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have one Eclipse RCP3 project.Now I need to call a rest api|(java) and Post some information using that API. Need Help.

Answer (score 1):

Being a Java application, an Eclipse RCP app can use most existing Java REST client libraries. My opinion is that the easiest way is to use the ECF JAX-RS Jersey Client. I recently wrote an article about how to incorporate this into an Eclipse RCP application:

https://www.modumind.com/2020/05/19/eclipse-rcp-and-rest-an-introduction/

In short, the JAX-RS Jersey Client is an OSGi Remote Services client created as part of the Eclipse Communications Framework (ECF) project. It embeds a Jersey/Jackson JAX-RS implementation that allows you to create REST clients as annotated interfaces that are made available as OSGi services locally. Jackson is used to data bind the REST responses to Java POJOs which require little or no annotation.

This solution allows you to skip most of the scaffolding code that usually has to be written to make REST calls in a Java application. But of course, you can also use Jersey and Jackson directly, those plugins are made available via Eclipse Orbit project.

http://www.eclipse.org/orbit

The GitHub repository for the ECF JAX-RS Jersey Client can be found here:

https://github.com/ECF/JaxRSProviders

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: 
[add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/251777) 
so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. 
[Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).